# I have a query with a between clause that is return wrong days

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm developing a scholl project and i have to return some data from a database(like in the query) and filter the data between 2 dates, so i do the query below.

```
Select L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, COUNT(*) AS NumeroAcessos, year,month,day
FROM L_AccessPoint INNER JOIN F_Presence ON L_AccessPoint.ap_id = F_Presence.ap_id
WHERE convert(varchar(10),F_Presence.ts, 120) between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-02'
Group by    L_AccessPoint.ap_id, ap_name, year,month,day
order by L_AccessPoint.ap_id ASC, year DESC,month DESC,day DESC
```

But when i execute this query that returns day in format yyyy-mm-dd 2022-02-28,2022-03-01,2022-03-02.
Like that: [image: The wrong return]

The table F_Presence structure is that:

[image: Table F_Presence structure]

The ts column is a datetime.

The table L_AcessPoint structure is that:

[image: Table L_AcessPoint structure]

How can I make the filter between those 2 dates?

How can I solve my problem?

Sorry everyone that tried to help but the problem is with my database, the ts is not corresponding with the month and day, like you can see:

[image]

I will be very grateful to everyone who helps me.

Comment: Also, `WHERE convert(varchar(10),F_Presence.ts, 120) between ....` isn't [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). A better way to compare dates is `WHERE Column >= '2022-03-01' AND < '2022-03-03'`. Note the use of `<`.

Comment: Ignoring the issues with BETWEEN and converting to char, it seems the values in columns "year", "month", and "day" do not match the value in column "ts". Is that what you mean by "solve my problem"?

Comment: @SMor the date is in format yyyy-mm-dd
And the problem is that the query returns 1 day that is not suposed to

Comment: _the query returns 1 day that is not suposed to_ So go find the rows that match that one day that is included using the appropriate ap_id value(s) and determine why they are included when you think they should not. That is basic debugging and no one can do that without examining your data directly. I will guess your join logic is faulty but have no idea how you might correct it.

Comment: You have bad data. You want a join to recognize when month/day/year are right but _also_ when they're wrong? You need to decide which one you trust and then _separately_ fix the rows that you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break this down:

```
WHERE convert(varchar(10),F_Presence.ts, 120) 
  between '2022-03-01' and '2022-03-02'
```

1. Converting the column to a string means you will never, ever, ever be able to take advantage of an index on that column, whether it exists yet or not.
2. Using `BETWEEN` is horrible for date ranges for multiple reasons.
3. Using a format like `YYYY-MM-DD` is unsafe, because it can be misinterpreted as `YYYY-DD-MM` in a lot of cases.

All these and more at [Dating Responsibly](https://sqlblog.org/dates).

Here is how the query should work:

```
WHERE F_Presence.ts >= '20220301'
  AND F_Presence.ts <  '20220303'
```

Comment: Nice answer but especially the "Dating Responsibly" Link name

Comment: Great run-down of all the typical date problems I see. Re #2: the term you want is a *half-open interval* as opposed to OP's *closed interval*